# JavaScript watch form fields and set session cookie

Tags: javascript

I'm a little rusty as it's been a long time since I've used much JavaScript. I'm wanting to watch all input fields within a form for the mouseout event and set a session cookie to store that value. Is there a neat way I can do this so I can watch all form fields within a form and avoid needing to watch one field at a time — I'm anticipating there could be a large number of fields so I want an efficient way to target them.

Say my form is:

```
<form action="#">
    <input id="form1_name" name="name" class="s_input" required="required" type="text">
    <input id="form1_email" name="email" class="s_input" required="required" type="text">
    <textarea id="form1_message" name="message" class="s_input" cols="30" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
    <input id="form1_submit" name="submit" class="s_input" value="Send" type="submit">
</form>
```

This is as far as I got with my JS, it currently fails with:

```
//get all the fields in question
var inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName('s_input');

//can see the inputs collected in an array
console.log(inputFields);

//fails
inputFields.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {   
});
```

I get an error of:

> TypeError: inputFields.addEventListener is not a function [Learn More]

Comment: Personally I'd do this using Knockout JS and a textInput binding and let it worry about doing it properly.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list; you need to iterate over that and call addEventListener on each item individually.

Comment: @Whelkaholism Thanks, I've never seen Knockout. I'll take a look!

Comment: @Doidgey You don't need a whole library for this.  You're 1 line of code away from it working.  Incidentally, are you sure you want to detect mouseleave on input fields?  If you're trying to detect value changes then use `.addEventListener("input", function....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('s_input');` Creates an array so to add anything to each element of the class `s_input` you need to loop over the collection.

Something like this should work:

```
for (i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) { 
   inputFields[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {  
    //event code here 
   });
}
```

Edit: Probably better to use `"blur"` event as mouseleave wont work if user is on a touch device or using keyboard only to tab through inputs.

Instead of attaching an event listener for blur you can do this:

```
 <input onblur="callYourFunction()" id="form1_name" name="name" class="s_input" required="required" type="text">
```